# angularJS json getting resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
            getTestimonials: function() {
                Requests.postData({
                        action1: 'getTestimonials'
                    }, {
                        market: "sg"
                    },
                    function(res) {
                      $scope.Testimonial = res.res;
                      console.log(res.res);
                    },
                    function(rej) {
                        console.log('rejected');
                    });
            },
```

[image]

I need to get airline name {{Testimonial}} give me :

> [{"VISITORNAME":"MICHAEL","DEPARTURE":"SINGAPORE","DESTINATION":"SHANGHAI","AIRLINE":"SINGAPORE
>   AIRLINES","TEXT":"VERY PROMPT AND EFFICIENT
>   SERVICE!"},{"VISITORNAME":"AMY","DEPARTURE":"SINGAPORE","DESTINATION":"JOHANNESBURG","AIRLINE":"QATAR
>   AIRWAYS","TEXT":"I LIASED THROUGH SALMA, WHO WAS EXTREMELY HELPFUL AND
>   COURTEOUS. EVEN THOUGH I WAS OCCUPIED IN MEETINGS OVER HTE COURSE OF 2
>   DAYS, WE MANAGED TO COMMUNICATE PROMPTLY OVER EMAIL. ONCE, WE BEGAN TO
>   FINALISE THE TRANSACTION SHE CONTACTED ME OVER THE
>   PHONE"},{"VISITORNAME":"ANTHONY","DEPARTURE":"SINGAPORE","DESTINATION":"SEOUL","AIRLINE":"SINGAPORE
>   AIRLINES","TEXT":"THIS IS MY FIRST EXPERIENCE WITH SKYLUX AND I TRAVEL
>   A LOT FOR BUSINESS. NELLY'S TURNAROUND ON EMAILS IS VERY QUICK AND
>   HELPFUL. OVERALL SERVICE IS 10/10."}]

Comment: You need to use ng-repeat and capture only the airline name from UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope.Testimonial` here is an array. Airline names are at `$scope.Testimonial[i].airline` where `i` is the index of the element you want to access.

If your view is using a loop (`ng-repeat`), you can do something like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="t in testimonial">{{t.airline}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

convert Json to a javascript object using angular.fromJson(jsonString).

```
var obj = angular.fromJson(jsonString);
// obj has an array of objects, so iterate the array to get the airline name and store it in any other array or use ng-repeat to show it in the html template

$scope.airlineDetails = angular.fromJson(jsonString);

//now in the html template,
<ul>
<li ng-repeat = "a in airlineDetails">a.airline</li>
</ul>
```